# How to get current windows user name in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 without IIS

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on issue in which my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app is hosted in Windows Service. I am using Kestrel without IIS. My requirement is that in multi user session environment like Citrix or Windows Server 2016 where multiple users can logged into the machine, I need to get the user name for each logged in user accessing the web app. The web app is an Outlook 365 web addin which only runs on the localhost and is not accessed by remote users.

Can you please provide some help on how to achieve this? That I should be able to get logged in user names/Ids in ASP.NET Core 3.1 which is not hoisted in IIS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get current windows login user in asp.net core? Not windows authentication login user.

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could set your asp.net core windows service enough permission and you could let asp.net core application run CMD command `whoami` to get the username.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var results = ps.AddScript("whoami").Invoke();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                string re = result.ToString();                
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply Brando. My application is hosted in Windows Service and this code is not working there.

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't set the enough permission for your application to  run the command?

Comment: yes I could not run the command from within the code running in the scope of Windows Service (system account)